# predicting exact probabilities in rpart decision tree model

Tags: r

rather than 0 or 1 ,how to calculate exact probabilities like 96% or 43% in rpart decision tree model.
I have tried 
predict(model,data,type="prob")
but it is predicting either 0 or 1

Comment: a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) might help. The default rpart prediction is probabilities for classification.

Answer (score 6):

During the creation of `rpart` object you have to specify `method = "class"` in parameters to ensure classification. Once you do that your predict method give probabilities with `type="prob"`.

Comment: I already tried that it is giving me probability as either 0 or 1.what I am trying to do is to find actual probabilities like .97  or .80

Comment: @NaziaAfreen perhaps your data is actually yielding the result as 0 or 1 as probabilities, i.e. you have a perfect fit and there is no chance of false positives. If you do the above steps correctly you should get probabilities as they are.

Answer (score 2):

@Nazia Afreen - below is the R scriptlet, hope this might help.

```
library(rpart)
model <- rpart(dependent_class_variable ~ independent var1 + var 2 + .., data = "your train data", method = "class")

## to get the probabilities of each record
probilities_ <- predict(model, "your test data without quotes", type = "prob")

## it will yield two probabilities, probability of getting class 1, and 
## probability of getting class 2, if you have two class. Sum of both = 1##
```